# Possible to set vimrc variables based on the current vim 'incantation'?

Tags: vimrc, variables

I wasn't sure how to word this properly in the title..

what I'm looking to do is set variables one way or another depending on how vim is invoked.
Specifically I have just discovered the `Man` plugin, and set my shell's `manpager` to `vim`.

When invoked as the manpager, I would like vim to use different default options for things like `spell` and `scrolloff` .. is this possible?

Comment: See this answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21703/5017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by working with the filetype.

To determine the filetype execute `:set ft?`

For the displayed man page this returns `man`.

If you want to set special settings for this filetype create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/man.vim`. All settings in this file will be loaded, when you open a man page.

There is already a default ftplugin (read "filetype plugin") for man pages. By placing your file below the subdir `.vim/after/ftplugin`, the default ftplugin is read first and then your file from the after-directory is read. This is the way to change or extend settings for a existing filetype.

BTW: On Windows it is `$HOME/vimfiles/after/man.vim`.

See `:h after-directory` and `:help ftplugin`.